# Using synchronized/locks in future code

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, playframework-2.0, akka

We are building a web app with Scala, Play framework, and MongoDB (with ReactiveMongo as our driver). The application architecture is non-blocking end to end.

In some parts of our code, we need to access some non-thread-safe libraries such as Scala's parser combinators, Scala's reflection etc. We are currently enclosing such calls in `synchronized` blocks. I have two questions:

1. Are there any gotchas to look out for when using `synchronized` with future-y code?
2. Is it better to use locks (such as `ReentrantLock`) rather than `synchronized`, from both performance and usability standpoint?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you mean by "future code"

Comment: @fge, code making heavy use of `Future`s. I thought that was sufficiently clear from the context (Play, Reactive* etc), but it seems it wasn't, so apologies.

Comment: You should not perform blocking operations with default execution context. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16834855/406435) may be useful.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question)) see here [using-actors-instead-of-synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215878/using-actors-instead-of-synchronized) for example. In short it would be more advisable to use actors instead of locks:

```
class GreetingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def receive = {
    case Greeting(who) ⇒ log.info("Hello " + who) 
  }
}
```

only one message will be processed at any given time, so you can put any not-thread safe code you want instead of log.info, everything will work OK. BTW using ask pattern you can seamlessly integrate your actors into existing code that requires futures.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what an "ask pattern" is and how to use it?

Comment: I could not do better than official documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Answer (score 3):

For me the main problem you will face is that any call to a synchronized or a locked section of code may block and thus paralyze the threads of the execution context. To avoid this issue, you can wrap any call to a potentially blocking method using `scala.concurrent.blocking`:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def synchronizedMethod(s: String) = synchronized{ s.size }

val f = future{ 
   println("Hello")
   val i = blocking{  //Adjust the execution context behavior
     synchronizedMethod("Hello")
   }
   println(i)
   i
 }
```

Of course, it may be better to consider alternatives like thread-local variables or wrapping invocation to serial code inside an actor.

Finally, I suggest using synchronized instead of locks. For most application (especially if the critical sections are huge), the performance difference is not noticeable.

Comment: +1 for the blocking() tip.  Agreed on using `synchronized` unless you want to take advantage of lock polling, timeouts, interruptibility, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The examples you mention i.e. reflection and parsing should be reasonably immutable and you shouldn't need to lock, but if you're going to use locks then a synchronized block will do. I don't think there's much of a performance difference between using synchronized vs Lock.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think the easiest and safest way would be (if at all you can) from **Thread Confinement**.
i.e. each thread creates its own instance of parser combinators etc and then use it.

And in case you need any synchronization (which should be avoided as under traffic it will be the killer), `synchornized` or `ReentrantLock` will give almost same performace. It again depends on what objects need to be Guarded on what locks etc. In a web-application, it is discouraged unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Can you please give more information on how to achieve thread confinement?